# form validation not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is my form :

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="AdminLoginCheck.jsp" onsubmit="return login()">
Enter your ID : <input type="text" name="master_admin_id" id="master_admin_id"><br>
Enter your Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And my javascript code for form validation is as follows :

```
<script>
        function login()
        {
            var master_admin_id = document.login.master_admin_id;                
            var password = document.login.password;
            if(master_admin_id.value == "")
            {
            window.alert("Enter your ID!");
            return false;
            }
            if(password.value == "")
            {
            window.alert("Enter your password!");
            return false;
            }
            return true;
        }            
        </script>
```

yet even if i press submit without entering the fields..., it is only reloading the page indicating that entered ID and password did not match in the database hence asking to enter again...

what could be the error?

Comment: Why have you tagged this Java?  There is no Java code here.  The "validation" all supposed happens in the browser-side javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `login` is already defined. It is your form. So when you call `return login()` it doesn't call your function, but try to return your form.

Just rename the function (or the form) and it will work.

Comment: Yep. Changing the name of the JavaScript function is doing the trick.